# Вывести 5 самых популярных ингрдиентов

Tags: sql, база-данных

Здравсвтуйте! У меня есть БД со списком коктейлей, в ней хранятся записи о коктейле и его ингредиентах. Мне нужно вывести 5 самых используемых игредиентов из бд, которые являются алкогольными. Пробовал сделать такой запрос в БД:

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT`component_id`)
FROM `cocktails`
WHERE `component_typeName`='alkohol' OR `component_typeName`='likier'
LIMIT (1,5)
```

Сама структура БД вот такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть в том, что у меня есть коктейль в нем ингрдиенты, и получается если у меня 5 ингрдиентов в коктейле у меня 5 записей, в которых будет отличаться id и информация о компоненте, если 2 ингредиента - 2 записи. Надеюсь, понятно все объяснил.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: *"У меня есть БД со списком коктейлей"* -- ну, по структуре похоже, что нет, скорее со списком пар коктейль-компонент. По-хорошему, эта таблица должна быть тремя разными таблицами: коктейлями, компонентами и связующей многие-ко-многим между ними.

Comment: берите просто count(), никакого max(count()) быть не может в принципе, добавьте group by. А так же order by, т.е. сортировку видимо по количеству на уменьшение

Comment: Да, я понимаю, но мне не очень хочется парится насчет архитектуры БД. Я пробовал вот так: 
SELECT (COUNT`component_id`) FROM `cocktails` WHERE `component_typeName`='alkohol' OR `component_typeName`='likier' LIMIT (1,5) GROUP BY `cocktail_id` DESC

Comment: Не изучали нормальные формы?

Comment: Да, но мне принципиально использование одной таблицы. Скажите, можно же как-то сгруппировать все это

Comment: посмотрите формат написания запросов. limit должен быть в самом конце. group by обеспечивает только группировку и у него нет параметров с порядком (т.е. desc) а порядок указывается в фразе ORDER BY

Comment: Смотрите, я смог вывести 5 самых испольщуемых алкогольных ингридиентов:
SELECT `component_id`,`component_name` count(`component_id`) FROM cocktail WHERE (`component_typeName`='alkohol' OR `component_typeName`='likier') GROUP BY `component_id` ORDER BY count(`component_id`) desc LIMIT 0,5
Можно ли как-то вывести 5 самых популярных ингридиентов,где будет 2 алкогольных?